# Keepass custom autotype sequence for all entries

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, passwords, password-management, keepass

I want to create a new auto-type like the default Auto-type which sends `{USERNAME}{TAB}{PASSWORD}{ENTER}`. In my case I would only like to send `{USERNAME}{TAB}{PASSWORD}` and leave out the enter keystroke and I'd like to create it for all entries and not for single entry. Can somebody help please.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all the entries' Auto-Type options are set to their default "*Inherit default auto-type sequence from group*", then just right-click the group those entries belong to, click "*Edit Group*", and then use the "Override" section of the "*Auto-Type*" tab to set a new sequence for all entries in that group.

If you want to edit ALL entries in ALL groups, then use the root group (usually named after your DB file) and edit as described above.

Comment: Yes but I'd like add one more sequence to the context menu with custom keyboard shortcut and not override the existing one. Is it possible?